# Iterating through a char array, assigning each char an integer corresponding to its alphabetical location

Tags: c#

I am trying to input a string into a C# console app, have it break the string into an array of its characters, and then have it iterate through the array of characters and assign each character an integer corresponding to its alphabetic position(1-26, a-z) and populate a new array with the integers.

The input block up to the array of characters I already have:

```
string plainText;
Console.Write ("String:");
plainText = Console.ReadLine();
char[] plainTextArray = plainText.ToCharArray();
```

Not looking for a completed solution, more of a suggested direction to look in for a function(s) to implement.

Thanks.

Comment: Question arising from [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/11861798) - What will you assign to non-letter characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions here:

- Convert the `char` to an `int`, subtract an appropriate amount to put it between 1-52, and take the number mod 26 (or .ToUpper() or ToLower() the string beforehand and put it in the 1-26 range)
- Create and prepopulate a mapping (something like `Dictionary<char, int>` that takes a `char` and returns the appropriate number

I recommend the first option.

**EDIT:**
Based on [phoog's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/11862111), I recommend the following method:

1. Use `String.ToUpper()` to convert the string to uppercase.
2. Use `String.ToCharArray()` to create the array of uppercase characters.
3. Create an `int[]` array that is the same size as the `char[]` array.
4. Iterate through the length of the arrays, converting char to int using `(plainTextArray[i] - 'a') + 1

Comment: The first solution will not work if the input contains characters outside of the a-z range.  The second solution is probably easier to implement then the logic to strip out any invalid characters.

Comment: True, but the question asks how to handle letters (granted the provided code does nothing to enforce this)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, input validation isn't needed since this is just a personal proof of concept and the input will only be within the a-z range.

Comment: Note that subtracting the char will implicitly convert it to an int.  The expression 'c' - 'a' evaluates to 2.